# Storing public key locally on android device

Tags: java, android, encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I want to use A-symmetric encryption for my application.
The application basically takes a photo and sends it to a server, I haven't written any code yet and am just going through this as a POC.
I came across a problem that I solved before but now it's puzzling me again.
Like I said I want to use Asymmetric encryption where the private key is located on my server, and the public key is stored locally and 'shipped' with each android app (I.E. including in its resources). I want to use the public key along with a `ByteOutputStream` or `EncryptedOutputStream` and send the information already encrypted to the server for decryption on site.
My question is basically how safe is the process of encrypting the data i'm sending out to the server? Obviously I understand that there is no such thing as completely safe, but is this a good practice, is there something that's sort of an industry-standard?

Comment: Asymmetric cryptography is **designed** to share public keys. It'a s mission of AC.

Comment: @NorthernPoet I adjusted the question a bit, hopefully this clears up what I'm confused about. Thanks.

Comment: Fine, it's a little clearer now. The answer is: choose proper AC algorithm. I will copypaste some details in answer.

Comment: You should just be using TLS.  It's industry standard and more secure than trying to implement your own system.  Have you considered authenticated encryption?  Hmac vs AEAD?  Forward secrecy?  TLS has!

Answer (score -1):

Copypaste from [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/what-are-the-realistic-and-most-secure-crypto-for-symmetric-asymmetric-hash) regarding asymmetric cryptography.

The currently largest broken RSA key is a 768-bit modulus, and it took some huge effort (four years, and really big brains). 1024-bit keys are considered usable for short term security, although larger keys are encouraged. 2048-bit keys are appropriate. Using a key twice larger means 8 times more work for signing or decryption, so you do not want to overdo it. See this site for a survey of how RSA key length can be related to security.

ECDSA over a 256-bit curve already achieves an "unbreakable" level of security (i.e. roughly the same level than AES with a 128-bit key, or SHA-256 against collisions). Note that there are elliptic curves on prime fields, and curves on binary fields; which kind is most efficient depends on the involved hardware (for curves of similar size, a PC will prefer the curves on a prime field, but dedicated hardware will be easier to build with binary fields; the CLMUL instructions on the newer Intel and AMD processors may change that).

Comment: Don't copy paste answers. Link to them in comments or mark this post as a duplicate.  Additionally, discussing how secure different key bit sizes are is somewhat trivial.  I feel like the OP is asking if his scheme is secure, not what algorithm and key size combinations are.